# Jhipster on prod build not being able to get base64Image from image upload ? But on Dev Build is Fine

Tags: reactjs, spring, jhipster

I'm using AntDesign Upload image for capturing base64 string.
Below is the code:

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MusicalRegisterIcon } from '../musicalRegisterIcon';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'app/config/store';
import { Link, Navigate, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { getEntity, createEntity, updateEntity } from 'app/entities/user-profile/user-profile.reducer';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';

import { reset } from '../register.reducer';
import axios from 'axios';

import { Form, Input, Select, Space, theme, Button, Upload, message, DatePicker } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { PlaysInput } from 'app/Components/editProfile/plays';
import { parseBioPicture, parseProfilePicture } from './profileCreationUtils';
import TextArea from 'antd/es/input/TextArea';
import moment from 'moment';

export default function ProfileCreation() {
  const isProfileCreated = useAppSelector(state => state.authentication.account.isProfileCreated);
  //   if (isProfileCreated === true) {
  //     return <Navigate to="/matching"></Navigate>; //reactivate later when making isProfileCreated
  //   }
  const Instrument = [
    'TROMBONE',
    'ELECTRICGUITAR',
    'PIANO',
    'GUITAR',
    'CELLO',
    'CLARINET',
    'BASSOON',
    'VIOLIN',
    'VOCALS',
    'FLUTE',
    'TRUMPET',
    'SITAR',
    'OBOE',
  ];
  const genres = [
    'ROCK',
    'POP',
    'BLUES',
    'COUNTRY',
    'ELECTRONIC',
    'FOLK',
    'HIPHOP',
    'JAZZ',
    'RANDB',
    'METAL',
    'PUNK',
    'CLASSICAL',
    'GRUNGE',
    'DNB',
    'HOUSE',
  ];
  const levels = ['grade 1', 'grade 2', 'grade 3', 'grade 4', 'grade 5', 'grade 6', 'grade 7', 'grade 8'];
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const regExp: RegExp = /^07[0-9]{9}$/;
  const id = useAppSelector(state => state.authentication.account.id);
  const isNew = true;

  const userProfileEntity = useAppSelector(state => state.userProfile.entity);
  const loading = useAppSelector(state => state.userProfile.loading);
  const updating = useAppSelector(state => state.userProfile.updating);
  const updateSuccess = useAppSelector(state => state.userProfile.updateSuccess);
  const [plays, setPlays] = useState([]);
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState([]);
  const { token } = theme.useToken();

  const handleClose = () => {
    navigate('/matching');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isNew) {
      dispatch(reset());
    } else {
      dispatch(getEntity(id));
    }
  }, []);

  const getProfileCreated = async () => {
    const accountRequest = await axios.get<any>('api/account');
    const userExtras = await axios.get<any>(`api/user-extras/${accountRequest.data.id}`);
    const userExtrasOnly = {
      isProfileCreated: userExtras.data.isProfileCreated,
    };
    const result = {
      id: accountRequest.data.id,
      isProfileCreated: userExtras.data.isProfileCreated,
    };
    return result;
  };

  const normFile = (e: any) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    return e?.fileList;
  };
  const beforeUpload = file => {
    const isImage = file.type.includes('img') || file.type.includes('image');
    if (!isImage) {
      message.error(`${file.name} is not an image file`);
    }
    return false;
  };

  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log(values);
    const dateOfBirth = moment(values.dateOfBirth).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const bioPics = parseBioPicture(values.bioPicture);
    const profilePicture = parseProfilePicture(values.profilePicture);
    const cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic = { ...values };
    delete cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic.profilePicture;
    delete cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic.bioPicture;
    const data = { ...bioPics, ...profilePicture, ...cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic, dateOfBirth };

    axios.post(`/api/create-user-profile/${id}`, data).then(() => {
      navigate('/matching');
    });
  };

  const defaultValues = () =>
    isNew
      ? {}
      : {
          ...userProfileEntity,
        };

  return (
    <div>
      <Row className="justify-content-center">
        <Col md="8" style={{ marginBottom: '50px', marginTop: '50px' }}>
          <h1 style={{ fontSize: 64, fontFamily: 'Capriola', fontWeight: 500 }}>Create User Profile</h1>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="justify-content-center">
        <Col style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', height: '100%' }} md="8">
          {loading ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : (
            <Form onFinish={onFinish} style={{ maxWidth: 600 }} autoComplete="off">
              <Form.Item name="university" label="University">
                <Input style={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: '8rem' }} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="dateOfBirth" label="DatePicker">
                <DatePicker style={{ marginLeft: '7.5rem' }} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="instagram" label="Instagram">
                <Input style={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: '8rem' }} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="bio" label="Biography">
                <TextArea style={{ marginLeft: '8rem' }} rows={4} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item
                name="phone"
                label="Phone Number"
                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your phone number, the format has to start with 07', pattern: regExp }]}
              >
                <Input style={{ width: '100%', marginLeft: '4rem' }} />
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.List
                name="plays"
                rules={[
                  {
                    async validator(_, play) {
                      if (play === undefined) {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error("Instrument can't be empty "));
                      } else {
                        if (play.includes(undefined) === false) {
                          const instruments = play.map(value => value.instrument);
                          for (let index = 0; index < instruments.length; index++) {
                            if (instruments.indexOf(instruments[index]) !== instruments.lastIndexOf(instruments[index])) {
                              return Promise.reject(new Error("Instrument can't have duplicates "));
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                ]}
              >
                {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                  <>
                    {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
                      <Space key={key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="baseline">
                        <Form.Item
                          style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
                          {...restField}
                          name={[name, 'instrument']}
                          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing Instrument' }]}
                        >
                          <Select placeholder={'Instrument'} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2rem' }}>
                            {Instrument.map((value, index) => (
                              <Select.Option key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2 rem' }} value={value}>
                                {value}
                              </Select.Option>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <Form.Item
                          {...restField}
                          name={[name, 'skillLevel']}
                          style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
                          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing Skill Level' }]}
                        >
                          <Select placeholder={'Skill Level'} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2rem' }}>
                            {levels.map((value, index) => (
                              <Select.Option key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2 rem' }} value={value}>
                                {value}
                              </Select.Option>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </Form.Item>

                        <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
                      </Space>
                    ))}
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Button
                        style={{ marginLeft: '16rem', maxWidth: '200px' }}
                        type="dashed"
                        onClick={() => add()}
                        block
                        icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                      >
                        Add Your Instrument
                      </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                  </>
                )}
              </Form.List>
              <Form.List
                name="likes"
                rules={[
                  {
                    async validator(_, play) {
                      if (play === undefined) {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error("Genres can't be empty "));
                      } else {
                        if (play.includes(undefined) === false) {
                          const likeslist = play.map(value => value.genre);
                          for (let index = 0; index < likeslist.length; index++) {
                            if (likeslist.indexOf(likeslist[index]) !== likeslist.lastIndexOf(likeslist[index])) {
                              return Promise.reject(new Error("Genres can't have duplicates "));
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                ]}
              >
                {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                  <>
                    {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
                      <Space key={key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="baseline">
                        <Form.Item
                          style={{ minWidth: '200px' }}
                          {...restField}
                          name={[name, 'genre']}
                          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing Genre' }]}
                        >
                          <Select placeholder={'Genres'} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2rem' }}>
                            {genres.map((value, index) => (
                              <Select.Option key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', minWidth: '2 rem' }} value={value}>
                                {value}
                              </Select.Option>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
                        </Form.Item>
                        <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
                      </Space>
                    ))}
                    <Form.Item>
                      <Button
                        type="dashed"
                        onClick={() => add()}
                        style={{ marginLeft: '16rem', maxWidth: '200px' }}
                        block
                        icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                      >
                        Add Your Genre
                      </Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                  </>
                )}
              </Form.List>
              <Form.Item name="bioPicture" label="Bio Picture (Max 3)" valuePropName="bioPicture" getValueFromEvent={normFile}>
                <Upload beforeUpload={beforeUpload} name="bioPicture" listType="picture-card" maxCount={3} accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg">
                  <div>
                    <PlusOutlined />
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload</div>
                  </div>
                </Upload>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item name="profilePicture" label="Profile Picture (Max 1)" valuePropName="profilePicture" getValueFromEvent={normFile}>
                <Upload beforeUpload={beforeUpload} name="profilePicture" listType="picture-card" maxCount={1} accept=".png,jpeg,.jpg">
                  <div>
                    <PlusOutlined />
                    <div style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>Upload</div>
                  </div>
                </Upload>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

const LikesInput = ({ likes, setLikes, token }) => {
  // const [plays, setPlays] = useState(defaultPlays);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Likes:');
    console.log(likes);
  }, [likes]);
  const genres = [
    'ROCK',
    'POP',
    'BLUES',
    'COUNTRY',
    'ELECTRONIC',
    'FOLK',
    'HIPHOP',
    'JAZZ',
    'RANDB',
    'METAL',
    'PUNK',
    'CLASSICAL',
    'GRUNGE',
    'DNB',
    'HOUSE',
  ];

  return (
    <Space wrap size={20} style={{ background: token.colorFillAlter, borderRadius: token.borderRadiusLG, padding: 24 }}>
      {likes.map((p, i) => {
        return (
          <Space key={i}>
            <Form.Item label="Instrument" style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
              <Select
                key={p.id}
                style={{ width: 120 }}
                value={likes.genre}
                onSelect={newValue => {
                  const newLikes = [...likes];
                  newLikes[i].instrument = newValue;
                  setLikes(newLikes);
                }}
              >
                {genres.map(instrument => {
                  return <Select.Option value={instrument}>{instrument}</Select.Option>;
                })}
              </Select>
            </Form.Item>
            <MinusCircleOutlined className="dynamic-delete-button" onClick={() => setLikes(likes.filter((p, j) => i !== j))} />
          </Space>
        );
      })}
      <Button
        icon={<PlusOutlined />}
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(likes.slice(-1)[0]);
          if (likes.length === 0 || !(likes.slice(-1)[0].instrument === '' && likes.slice(-1)[0].skillLevel === '')) {
            // add new element if empty or last element is not blank
            setLikes(likes.concat({ instrument: '' }));
          }
        }}
      ></Button>
    </Space>
  );
};
```

For some reason on dev build using getting the base64 string is possible here is the result from the function onFinish()

```
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log(values);
    const dateOfBirth = moment(values.dateOfBirth).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    const bioPics = parseBioPicture(values.bioPicture);
    const profilePicture = parseProfilePicture(values.profilePicture);
    const cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic = { ...values };
    delete cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic.profilePicture;
    delete cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic.bioPicture;
    const data = { ...bioPics, ...profilePicture, ...cleanedValuesFromBioandProfilePic, dateOfBirth };

    axios.post(`/api/create-user-profile/${id}`, data).then(() => {
      navigate('/matching');
    });
  };
```

Result on Dev Build
[image]

Result on Prod Build
[image]

As you can see on Prod Build it won't work, it's definitely not React's problem but more of there is a setting I haven't figured out yet. Can someone tell me why this is ? Thanks